# Shift + E not working on Dell Inspirion; Shift Buttons and E key is individually working well

Tags: keyboard, dell-inspiron

I have a strange problem on my Dell Inspirion's laptop keyboard: The <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> Keystroke does not seem to be working.

I tried with both left and right <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys. Same problem.

The <kbd>Shift</kbd> key themselves seem to be fine since all other <kbd>Shift</kbd>+letter combinations come out correctly. Also the e key itself seems fine since I have no trouble typing the non-Caps E.

Any ideas how I could fix it? Or troubleshooting Steps? I tried the Windows Keyboard troubleshooter but it detected no problems.

<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> is also working fine. If it matters this is Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel, Ease of Access, and in the the window that comes up, look for "Make the Keyboard Easier to use". Turn off all the settings there.

Check through the other settings in Ease of Access (Use the computer without Mouse or Keyboard) as well. See if the On Screen Keyboard has been enabled.

Then, if the above settings are OK, try running DISM and SFC. This may correct underlying operating system issues.

Open an admin command prompt and run first:
dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth

And then second:
SFC /SCANNOW

When both are complete, restart and test.

Comment: Thanks! I checked and none of that is enabled!

Comment: You may need to run the basic Windows 10 corrections - DISM and SFC.  I added that to my answer above.